# Logging package recommendation for R

Tags: r, r-package

Which logging package would you recommend for R? I am aware there are several packages available but would like to know which one is considered the best. Specifically, here is what I am looking for:

- multiple logging level
- built-in support for rotating log file
- fast (should not slow down too much existing code)
- painless to setup (not too much boilerplate code)

Comment: @Louis it might help if you edited your question to be more specific. What requirements or features are you looking for in a logging package?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did not see the potential duplicate.

Comment: @Louis: have a look at the [logging package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928332) I developed and am maintaining.  if you miss anything, file a bug report.  about the speed, I don't know, isn't R lazy enough that this is not an issue?  but I'm interested in making it better, all usable evidence it's not good enough will be welcome!

Comment: @Mario actually, I have used and still use this package. It works well for my need. Thanks for creating and sharing it. What would be great is rotating file handler.

Comment: @Louis: I just opened a [feature request](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1289&group_id=672&atid=2710) for the rotating file handler.  you run on Windows, don't you?

Comment: @Mario Thank you. Yeah I am on windows. I will have a look at (http://www.datori.org/?p=7) Maybe it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

For simple logging, evaluate ?sink

Comment: I use 'sink' a lot but it's not exactly a logging package.