# How do you calculate cyclomatic complexity for R functions?

Tags: r, complexity-theory, cyclomatic-complexity

[Cyclomatic complexity](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) measures how many possible branches can be taken through a function.  Is there an existing function/tool to calculate it for R functions?  If not, suggestions are appreciated for the best way to write one.

A cheap start towards this would be to count up all the occurences of `if`, `ifelse` or `switch` within your function.  To get a real answer though, you need to understand when branches start and end, which is much harder.  Maybe some R parsing tools would get us started?

Comment: Related to this, it can be useful to see how many branches actually are taken.  For that, various code coverage metrics can help.  I don't yet know of any code coverage tools for R, though.

Comment: Could [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125898/tool-for-calculating-cyclomatic-complexity) be related?  The [metrics plugin](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/) for Eclipse might just make me use Eclipse again, if this works for R.

Comment: Sorry for the abundance of comments, but I prefer to post answers with answers.  :)  Can you clarify why you'd like the cyclomatic complexity?  In practice, I find that handling of outliers and bad data require lots of separate if-statements in my code, which will run up the cyc. comp. a lot.  This isn't bad, but the actual coverage of executed (both in testing and deployment) code is important for being sure that outliers and anomalies are handled.

Comment: I erred - the metrics plugin is [just for Java](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/).  What is the sound of one hope crushing?

Comment: High cyclomatic complexity can be used as a proxy for "maybe I should refactor this code" or at least "Richie, you've gotten yourself muddled and overcomplicated things".  It just gives another way of weeding out cr*ppy code.

Comment: You might really consider looking at code coverage relative to lines of code.  If you have a lot of code that isn't executed in testing, then there is a problem. Also, code that is regularly used tends to be more correct (because usage is a form of testing :)) than unused code.

Comment: @Brandon: `testthat` doesn't seem to have a function to measure of code complexity.

Comment: I don't have a proof (and if I did, it would be marvelous, yet not fit in the margins afforded by a comment box), but I suspect it is possible to create a program with infinite cylomatic complexity, where checking it would not be decidable.  In short, I suspect that checking cyclomatic complexity could be a form of the halting problem.  Then again, I just found that Wikipedia already mentions this: search for halting problem in [this entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage).  It's not a proof, but I suspect it could be done.

Comment: I think that `eval(parse(text = nefariousArbitraryInputStringWithLotsOfStochasticBranching))` could be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, I just found a new package called cyclocomp (released 2016). Check it out!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `codetools::walkCode` to walk the code tree. Unfortunately codetools' documentation is pretty sparse. Here's an explanation and sample to get you started.

`walkCode` takes an expression and a code walker. A code walker is a list that you create, that must contain three callback functions: `handler`, `call`, and `leaf`. (You can use the helper function `makeCodeWalker` to provide sensible default implementations of each.) `walkCode` walks over the code tree and makes calls into the code walker as it goes.

`call(e, w)` is called when a compound expression is encountered. `e` is the expression and `w` is the code walker itself. The default implementation simply recurses into the expression's child nodes (`for (ee in as.list(e)) if (!missing(ee)) walkCode(ee, w)`).

`leaf(e, w)` is called when a leaf node in the tree is encountered. Again, `e` is the leaf node expression and `w` is the code walker. The default implementation is simply `print(e)`.

`handler(v, w)` is called for each compound expression and can be used to easily provide an alternative behavior to `call` for certain types of expressions. `v` is the character string representation of the parent of the compound expression (a little hard to explain--but basically `<-` if it's an assignment expression, `{` if it's the start of a block, `if` if it's an if-statement, etc.). If the handler returns `NULL` then `call` is invoked as usual; if you return a function instead, that's what's called instead of the function.

Here's an extremely simplistic example that counts occurrences of `if` and `ifelse` of a function. Hopefully this can at least get you started!

```
library(codetools)

countBranches <- function(func) {
  count <- 0
  walkCode(body(func), 
           makeCodeWalker(
             handler=function(v, w) {
               if (v == 'if' || v == 'ifelse')
                 count <<- count + 1
               NULL  # allow normal recursion
             },
             leaf=function(e, w) NULL))
  count
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  `codetools` looks very useful, though I see what you mean about the sparse documentation.  I'm gonna have to play with this a little before I can get my head around what's going on.

Comment: Nice! I also have a few draft functions at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language.  Personally, I don't think the codeWalker stuff is mature enough to have much advantage over doing it by hand.